# How to send parameters from screen to stack navigator?

Tags: react-native

I am a newbie to react native.
I am using a stack navigator inside a tab navigator; I have to navigate multiple screens inside each tab. i am able to send parameters from my default class HomePage to my nested classes in my tab and stack navigators.

```
export const MyApp = TabNavigator({
Asset: {
screen: AssetScreen,
},
Sensors: {
screen: sensorsStack,
},
Settings: {
    screen: settingStack
 },
}
export const sensorsStack = StackNavigator({
sensors : { screen: SensorScreen },
sensorDetails : { screen: SensorDetails }
});
export const settingStack = StackNavigator({
 settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
 about : { screen: About },
 environment : { screen: Environment }
});

export default class HomePage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   assetID:'xyz',
   authToken:'xyzz'
  }
}
static navigationOptions = {
  header: null
};
render() {
    const screenProps = {
        asset: {
            assetID: this.state.assetID,
            authToken : this.state.authToken,
        },
    }
    return (
        <MyApp screenProps={screenProps} />
    );
}
}
```

Now, i want to send a parameter from 'SensorScreen' to 'SensorDetails'. I have tried sending parameters using

```
 NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'sensorDetails' ,params: { sensorType:'Fuel',}});
```

from 'SensorScreen' class. But was not able to get the parameter in 'SensorDetails' class. How can i pass this params?

Answer (score 2):

A little late answer but might help others that ends up here. 
Instead of using NavigationActions you could try navigation from sensorScreen to sensorDetails with navigate and passing some extra variables.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('SensorDetails',{sensorType:'Fuel'})
```

The passed object can then be read in the second screen by

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.sensorType
```

A minimal example of the case can be seen in these lines. Observe that this is a stupid on icon tab bar. But it is kept that way since the question was about a tab bar with stacks on each tab. And new tabs are easily added.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import { Text, View, Footer,Button } from 'react-native'
import {StackNavigator,TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

export class SensorScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<Button
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SensorDetails',{sensorType:'Fuel'})}
              title="Go to Sensor Details"
            />)}}

export class SensorDetails extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<View>
              <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.sensorType}</Text>
            </View>);}
  }

const sensorsStack = StackNavigator({
  sensors : { screen: SensorScreen },
  SensorDetails : { screen: SensorDetails }
});

const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Sensors: {
    screen: sensorsStack,
  },
});

export default class Nested extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <MyApp/>
    );
}
}
```

Hope this helps.